# Odoo - how to hide conversations icon in menu bar

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, systray

I'm customizing odoo community v14 
We don't use the discuss module but it was installed by other modules we use, so I've removed the 'Discuss' menu item, but I can't find how to remove the conversions icon just at the left of were the the activity  icon  and  user name is shown.
I found a response for a similar [question](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-can-i-hide-system-tray-icons-in-menu-bar-by-the-side-of-user-name-115512) in odoo forum but I couldn't find the code of this icon in `addons/mail/static/src/xml/systray.xml` only the code of activity icon is present
I searched for some parts of the html code in entire odoo source code but with no result
Any help please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using css by adding `li.o_MessagingMenu{display: none !important;}` to `addons/web/static/src/scss/navbar.scss`